# How to write character x in math enviroment as Polykov's book?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, packages, languages, windows

I am using Latex. I want to write x as in Polykov's book, but I do not konw which font it is.
[image: Ployakov's x]

It is like chi, but it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be Bitstream Charter text with Math Design math.

It is just an x, not chi.

Use `\usepackge[charter]{mathdesign}` to employ this type of font.

More information about free fonts in Latex, see
[enter link description here](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this package.

Comment: If I use this package, then all the characters are changed. Is there any way just to change the character which I want to make different? for example, like \mathcal{}.

Answer (score 2):

The `xcharter` package has five different [recommended preambles](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/xcharter/doc/xcharter-doc.pdf) for this font, all of them for PDFLaTeX.  The disadvantage of using `mathdesign` is that it breaks `mathalpha`, making it difficult to replace the default `\mathcal` with a better one.

If you’re using the modern toolchain, you would load the letters of XCharter over your math font, for example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{XCharter}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range=it]{XCharter Italic}
\setmathfont[range=up]{XCharter Roman}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{XCharter Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{XCharter Bold}

\newcommand\dint[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{d}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[ G \left( x, x' \right) =
     \int \left( \frac{\mathcal{D} x(\tau)}{\mathcal{D} f(\tau)} \right)
       \exp \left( -m_0 \int\limits_0^1
                          \left(\dot{x}^2 (\tau)\right)^{1/2}
                        \dint{\tau}
            \right) 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: XCharter/Libertinus Math sample]

XCharter is a fork of the free version of Charter that Bitstream donated to the X Consortium in 1992.  One disadvantage is that *v* and *ν* (nu) might be too similar.  Charis SIL is another free font based on Charter.

(Thanks to Sebastiano for some tips on better matching the typesetting of the book. You might try `\frac{1}{2}` or `\sfrac` from `xfrac` instead of `{1/2}`.)

Comment: I tried the package, but it does not work. Maybe my latex is too old.